# calculating entropy in a sequence of letters

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, entropy, traminer

I am trying to calculate shannon's entropy of sequence of letters, for example,

```r
A <- c('A-A-A-A', 'A-B-C-D-E-E', 'A-B-D-F-G-E')
```

I am trying to use the TraMineR ways to do so, but as I already have a sequene object I am unable to do so using the traMineR package, see  below:

http://traminer.unige.ch/doc/seqient.html

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Isn't this as simple as `seqient(seqdef(A))` or am I missing something? Is the problem that you *"already have a sequene object"*? Please explain the problem better, including the code that produced that object.

Comment: yeah but A is not a sequence object and seqdef is not working as sequences are calculated from a wide format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
library(TraMineR)
A<- c( 'A-A-A-A', 'A-B-C-D-E-E', 'A-B-D-F-G-E')
B <- as.data.frame(A)
actcal.seq <- seqdef(B)
## Summarize and plot histogram
## of within sequence entropy
actcal.ient <- seqient(actcal.seq)
summary(actcal.ient)
hist(actcal.seq)
```

[image]

UPDATE: Per OP's request, adding Entropy to original data:

```
 cbind(B, actcal.ient)
#              A   Entropy
#[1]     A-A-A-A 0.0000000
#[2] A-B-C-D-E-E 0.8020465
#[3] A-B-D-F-G-E 0.9207822
```